# Execute C# from joomla

Tags: c#, asp.net, joomla

I use to work with Asp.Net, so I am used to deal with the classic way : **HTML page and some Java-script and a C# code behind**, but lately I wanted to use CMS : precisely `Joomla`.

The website I am working on does some heavy treatment to an image, I only can do that with C# on `Asp.Net`, now that I want to build the same thing on `Joomla`:

I was wondering if `Joomla` can allow me to use my C# code in the Server side? If not what do you suggest me?

Comment: You could create a web service to do this. Use PHP to make a service call out to your C# web server, and then have it respond back. Are you sure C# is the ONLY way to do this though, or are you just looking to "get the job done"?

Comment: Honestly, i guess the job can be done in php, (and by the way, i'm planning on doing this in the future) but i don't have time right now, i'm in a hurry, i need to get this done ASAP !
and for you idea about web service, first : can i use WCF ? and second : can i host both : the web service and the website in the same space ?

Comment: Sure, you can host both in the same space as long as wherever you're hosting it can host ASP.NET applications or whatever you'd like. You can use WCF.

Comment: Create rest based APIs like `web-api` and invoke that from anywhere like `Joomla` in your case.